Is it possible to fold output from quarto chunk?
When I render quarto reports I often use the code-fold option to make the code accessible in the final report without it disrupting the report.
```{python}
#| code-fold: true

print('hello')

```

Is there a similar option for folding the output of the chunk? This would be useful for output that I'd like available in the report but don't want displayed by default.
for example sessionInfo() will output an enormous amount of text that is only relevant to a limited set of readers ... so I'd love to include it but only within a fold.
```{r}
sessionInfo()
```


Keep an eye on the issue #341 on the quarto github repository asking for the output folding feature. Note that, the workaround proposed in that issue thread, will work only for R code cell, not python code cell.

Use collapse=true as in {.callout-note collapse=true}
collapse=true

where would such code be placed? Clearly it's not a chunk option.

Did you find the solution?
